# Datatable jquery fnAddData

Tags: jquery, datatables

Managed to pull out this together which moves rows back and forth between two datatables BUT there is a glitch somewhere I can't find. Core function is this.

```
    stockTable.on('click', '.toggle' ,function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var addRow = stockTable.fnGetData($(this).closest('tr')[0]);
    stockTable.fnDeleteRow($row.index());
    catalogTable.fnAddData(addRow);
});
```

The thing is "sometimes" when clicking buttons repeatedly it sends the wrong row!

Take a look please and make sure you click the buttons randomly and repeatedly. http://jsfiddle.net/NpT26/3/

Thanks!

Comment: Wow ! Credit for creating fiddle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Funny, I *just* did this for my own project last week.  Here is what I notice that seems off:

- You select the row multiple times.  Only do it once.
- You pass the row index to `.fnDeleteRow()`.  Instead, pass the row itself.  The method accepts either, and you already have a reference to the row.
- You first delete the row, then add the data to the other table.  Add the data to the other table first, then delete the row.  I can't say definitively that this is causing any problems, but it seems more likely to encounter some sort of race condition if you delete the row first.

Making those changes you get:

```
stockTable.on('click', '.toggle', function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
    var addRow = stockTable.fnGetData(row);
    catalogTable.fnAddData(addRow);
    stockTable.fnDeleteRow(row);
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/NpT26/13](http://jsfiddle.net/NpT26/13/)

---

You can reduce the redundancy of your code by using the same object to initialize both tables, and using a generalized version of your click handler:

[jsfiddle.net/NpT26/14](http://jsfiddle.net/NpT26/14/)

Comment: Good answer, +1 - hopefully the OP will appreciate it

Comment: Can't upvote since I need 15 of reputation...a shame. Great answer, gilli3 that solved my problem! THANKS A LOT you've shed light onto me! thanks to david too for previous answer.